# Truck still overheating after radiator and thermostat replacement

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, silverado

2000 Chevrolet Silverado 5.3 overheating drove vehicle to work and blew the top of my radiator.   So i replace the rad. And thermostat thinking that's my problem.   Bleed the system turn on heater in vehicle waited to get heat no heat at all bleed system again. I revved the engine: nothing. Could my heater core be causing my overheating problem?

Comment: Exactly how are you bleeding the system?

Comment: If the heater core was broken/clogged, the truck wouldn't overheat, but you might not get heat in the cabin. As soon as the truck warmed up, the thermostat would open, which would allow hot coolant to enter the radiator, and cold coolant from the radiator would get sucked into the engine.

Answer (score 1):

did you try leaving the rad cap off when first cranking the engine waiting until the thermostat opens to see if the coolant is circulating ...may be the water pump impeller thats defective...if no movement then chances are the water pump is shot

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the **water pump** is broken.

This would explain why you aren't getting any heat; the water pump isn't pushing hot coolant to the heater core.

It would also explain why the engine is overheating even after you replaced the thermostat; the water pump isn't pushing/pulling enough hot/cold coolant out of/into the engine

This should be easy to test. When the truck is cold, start the engine. The thermostat probably won't open for a couple minutes, so the water pump will *only* be pumping coolant to the heater core. Locate the heater core inlet and outlet hoses on the firewall (probably to the left of the engine?). Unplug both hoses from the heater core. If the water pump is working fine, the hose which takes hot coolant out of the engine will start shooting coolant everywhere.